# Configure Maven settings for deployment

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I want to deploy artifacts to Nexus from Jenkins to different repositories (like `builds-all`, `builds-verified`, `releases`). The thing is that I want to keep minimal configuration in the project POM file. My settings file now looks like:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>orion-nexus</id>
        <username>admin</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>

<localRepository>~/.m2/repository</localRepository>

<profiles>
    <!-- Deployment configuration for CI builds for mainline -->
    <profile>
        <id>build</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>builds-all</id>
                <url>http://orion-nexus:8081/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Project POM:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>orion-nexus</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url><!-- how to avoid explicit URL? --></url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I wan to run deploy like `mvn -B -P build clean install deploy`. However, I don't understand how to avoid setting explicit URL in distribution management section. Can I set a variable in settings file and propagate it to my POM?

Is there any step-by-step guide for such workflow?

Comment: Why do you not want a URL here? It's the perfect place for it: each project declares where it should be pushed. There was a long mail about this on the [Maven mailing list](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Can-t-specify-distributionManagement-in-settings-xml-td3181781.html) that will interest you. At the end of it, you'll agree :)

Comment: If you need it for more than one project simply start creating a corporate pom which defines this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a property inside a [profile](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles) on your `settings.xml` and use its name within `<distributionManagement/>` configuration.

**settings.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>distmgt</id>
        <properties>
            <distUrl>scp://...</distUrl>
        <properties/>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>orion-nexus</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>${distUrl}</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

And finally

```
mvn -P distmgt clean deploy
```

You can avoid the `-P build` params using [activation](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation).